# Fullscreen videoview inside recyclerview

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, android-recyclerview, android-videoview

In recyclerview i want when i click full screen button the videoview must play in fullscreen mode. But i don't want to use another activity for videoview fullscreen. Is there any best way possible to do this.

```
            DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
            int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
            int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
            android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (android.widget.FrameLayout.LayoutParams) surfaceView.getLayoutParams();
            params.width = width;
            params.height = height;// -80 for android controls
            params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
            fullscreenExit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            fullscreen.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            title.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            mediaPlayer.start();
```

using above method makes the videoview fullscreen in the recyclerview. i want the videoview only should be visible in the fullscreen mode.

Comment: you can use fragment

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have 3 choices to have a fullscreen on a player:

1. Use an `Activity`
2. Use a `Fragment`
3. When going to fullscreen, move the view to the rootView and set it to `match_parent`. To do this, you will have to remove the videoView and add it to the root view after.

Comment: how to implement 3 option?

Comment: well, read the doc ? as I sayed, you need to manipulate dynamicaly views, remove it and add it later on.